# Starting a process from in line code in Java

Tags: java, linux

I'm wondering if it's possible to start a process and have it run code from the current program in Java similar to `fork()` in C. What I'd like to do is:

```
public void someMethod() {
    doStuff();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* start someMethod() in separate process */

    doOtherStuff();
}
```

To clarify I DON'T want to run someMethod() from a separate file the way ProcessBuilder etc. allows, I want it to be from in line code if that makes sense.

NOTE: this is a Java related conceptual question, i.e. please don't ask "Why don't you run someMethod() in a thread instead?"

Comment: Java uses threads, not processes, so you can run `someMethod()` in a thread.  A thread is better than a process in almost every way ('d say literally every way), so there was no need to include a separate process API.

Comment: "thread is better than a process" - not if I intentionally want a different address space for a my program :)

Comment: what are you actually trying to solve here? why can you not achieve this by using threads? why care about address space in **Java**?

Comment: As I stated in my note, this is purely conceptual to understanding the language, no real practical purpose. 
Also fwiw you *do* care about address space in Java for several applications such as working with outside api that you want for to have a separate file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to spawn a process and run a method in java the way you want since java uses threads.

To run it into a separate process, you can  compile the code as a separate application and call it using process api.

Comment: Or dive down to C/C++ via JNI and use `fork()` :)

Comment: So is this something to do with the fact that it runs on a JVM layer? I don't fully understand why C/C++ can achieve this but Java cannot

Comment: Yes.. as far as I know java multithreading was built on top of pthread. Thread provides lot of capability. They are lightweight, can share memory which would be difficult to achieve via process.